# is there an Ecto wrapper for arangodb in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, arangodb, ecto

I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix and I was wondering if there is an Ecto wrapper for AQL in phoenix?

I wrote a simple wrapper for CRUD actions but I wanted something more powerful and complete to be able to make queries like Ecto.Query.

is there an Ecto wrapper for the ArangoDB in phoenix?

Comment: There is https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/arangodb_ecto; last activity happend a while ago.

Comment: I saw this. but it's not as strong as I need, and the last commit was made more than a year ago. it's not up to date.

Comment: Yes, I did not find the time to work on this more (I am the author of the previously mentioned one), so it is still stuck on Ecto 2. However, in the meantime there is a new library: https://github.com/TomGrozev/arangox_ecto I will probably deprecate mine in favor of that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after a while, I found this on github:

https://github.com/TomGrozev/arangox_ecto

it's handy and can solve my issues.